# Rebuild Graph by Related Entities in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a Cypher beginner. I tried to google my issue but could not find an answer.

Assume `node-1` has a relationship to `svc-1`, `node-2` has a relationship to `svc-2`, and `node-2` has a relationship to `node-1`.

Is it possible to make a query that looks for a path between `node-1` and `node-2` in order to create a relationship between `svc-1` and `svc-2`?

For example, we have the following data

```
[
    {
        "spanId":"3",
        "name": "checkOut",
        "parentId": "2",
        "service_name": "svc-2"
    },
    {
        "spanId":"4",
        "name": "payment",
        "parentId": "3",
        "service_name": "svc-2"
    },
    {
        "spanId":"2",
        "name": "addCart",
        "parentId": "1",
        "service_name": "svc-1"
    },
    {
        "spanId":"1",
        "name": "frontend",
        "service_name": "svc-1"
    }
]
```

we have

1. `frontend -> addCart` for `svc-1`
2. `checkOut -> payment` for `svc-2`
3. `addCart -> checkOut`.

[image]

From the span view, we have the path `frontend -> addCart -> checkOut -> payment`, but from service, I wish to have `svc-1 -> svc-2` and only show it. Is there cypher query to make it?

Comment: Are each of those items separate nodes (4 nodes?) What do you mean by svc-1 -> svc-2 ? Do you want to traverse or return as results ?

Comment: @aldrin Yes. I just added a graph above. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @TripleH I edited the wording of your question. Does this sentence accurately reflect what you want?: "Is it possible to make a query that looks for a path between `node-1` and `node-2` in order to create a relationship between `svc-1` and `svc-2`"? Or are you just trying to create a query that returns `svc-1` and `svc-2` without creating a relationship between them?

Answer (score 4):

If you actually just want to see the names of `svc-1` and `svc-2` if a `PARENT_OF` path exists from `node-1` to `node-2`:

```
MATCH (s1:Service)<-[:FROM_SERVICE]-(n1:Node)-[:PARENT_OF*..7]->(n2:Node)-[:FROM_SERVICE]->(s2:Service)
WHERE n1.name = 'frontend' AND n2.name = 'payment'
RETURN s1.name AS s1_name, s2.name AS s2_name
```

I limited the variable-length path search to a somewhat-arbitray depth of 7, to avoid the query taking too long or running out of memory (if you had a lot of data).

I would advise against actually creating a new relationship between `svc-1` and `svc-2` because that would be storing redundant information AND it may actually be confusing (since not all possible `PARENT_OF` paths would have the same pair of service nodes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried the query you provided above (with slight change): 

MATCH (s1:Service)<-[:FROM_SERVICE]-(n1:Span)-[:PARENT_OF*..7]->(n2:Span)-[:FROM_SERVICE]->(s2:Service)
WHERE n1.name = 'frontend' AND n2.name = 'payment'
RETURN s1, s2

It showed `svc-1` and `svc-2` but didn't create a relationship `svc-1 -> svc-2`.

Comment: Right, so it worked as was intended (not creating new relationship).